# How to restrict copy/download/print access for a file using Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

has anyone found a way to restrict copy/download/print access for a spreadsheet using google apps script? Background info: I created a script which restricts share rights for editors using setShareableByEditors(false). The only problem is that editors can still easily make a copy of the spreadsheet and then share it widely. I know that there's an option to manually restrict this setting in Google Sheets, but this solution is not scalable as I'm trying to manage share settings for a high number of spreadsheets. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by [enabling](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) and using the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive). You would set the `file`'s `restricted` label to `true`. Here's an example:

```
function restrictFile() {

  var id = '10iM3V2q7FQWBAxy93eN9jvbp_SFco-KLPibeG9XRr71';

  // get the file with the Advanced Drive API (REST V2)
  var file = Drive.Files.get(id);
  Logger.log('File "%s", restricted label was: %s', file.title, file.labels.restricted);

  // set the restricted label
  file.labels.restricted = true;

  //update the file
  Drive.Files.update(file, id);

  // check the updated file
  var updatedFile = Drive.Files.get(id);
  Logger.log('File "%s", restricted label is: %s', updatedFile.title, updatedFile.labels.restricted);

}
```

You can confirm it also in the UI under File > Share... > Advanced:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible to restrict commenters and viewers from copy/download/print. It is not possible to restrict editors in the same way unfortunately.