# google apps script: is it possible to restrict the sharing settings of a file while still sending a sharing notification?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, sharing

I have written a Google Apps Script function that is meant to share Google Drive files, but prevent the recipient from copying/downloading/printing said files.

```
function shareFile(Id,addr,role,opt,msg){
  var sendNotifications;
  var fileId = Drive.Files.get(Id);
  Logger.log('File "%s", restricted label was: %s', fileId.title, fileId.labels.restricted);

  
  // cambia l'etichetta per limitare l'accesso (stampa, copia, scarica)
  // changes the labels in order to restrict access
  if(opt == 0) fileId.labels.restricted = true;
  else fileId.labels.restricted = false;
  
  // aggiorna le proprietà
  // update labels
  Drive.Files.update(fileId, Id);
   
  // notifiche
  // notifications
  if(msg==="") sendNotifications='false';
  else sendNotifications='true';
   
   
 Drive.Permissions.insert(
        {
         'role': role,
         'type': 'user',
         'value': addr
        },
        Id,
        {
         'sendNotificationEmails': sendNotifications,
         'emailMessage': msg
         });       
}
```

In writing this function I was inspired by [this](https://www.labnol.org/code/20101-share-files-google-drive-without-email-notifications) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103407/how-to-restrict-copy-download-print-access-for-a-file-using-google-apps-script).

My function does seem to work when no notification is sent to the recipient (the last argument is empty, msg="").
In this case the file appears in the "Shared with me" section of the recipient's Google Drive, and the only possible action for them is to create a shortcut to it. No download, copy, print, share allowed.

When msg is non empty, an email notification is sent to the recipient. The problem is that the document is attached to the email and the recipient can download it (and hence distribute it).
Yet, if the document is opened from the "Shared with me" section of the recipient's Google Drive it appears to be still restricted. The recipient cannot download, print or copy it.

I find this a little weird, but maybe this is the intended behavior.

In principle I'd like to notify the recipient that a file was shared with him/her, possibly including a Google Drive link. Attaching the document to the email seems to defeat the purpose of the restricted labels. But I'm probably missing something, and chances are that what I want could be achieved in a much cleaner way.

I did some research, but ended up more confused.
If I get it right, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198377/gdrive-disable-copying-and-downloading) Tanaike says that "labels.restricted" is deprecated.
Could this be the reason why my script fails (assuming that it actually fails)?
I still do not really understand Tanaike's workaround.

Thanks a lot for any insight
Francesco

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. I have 3 questions. 1. In your script, can I ask you about the value of `role`? 2. If `role` is `writer`, it seems that the Document can be downloaded and be copied even when `copyRequiresWriterPermission` is `true`. Is this related to `The problem is that the document is attached to the email and the recipient can download it (and hence distribute it).`? 3. When I saw the notification email, a shortcut can be created. But it seemed that the download cannot be done on email. How about this?

Comment: Hi Tanaike. What I meant is that your solution is too advanced for me to understand right now.  I was actually planning to study it. .

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about my 3 questions?

Comment: I was anyways curious about the fact that, apparently, including a message breaks the restrictions on the file. Also, you're right, I forgot to mention what  the role of the recipients is. Since  they are only supposed to see the document, but not distribute it in any way, I set the role to 'reader'. The remaining parameters should be obvious: addr is the address, and opt=0 so that the file is restricted. I do not understand your item 3, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About 3, when the Google Docs in the notification email is seen, the shortcut can be created. But the Google Docs cannot be copied and downloaded. I wanted to ask whether this situation is the same with yours. And, when `reader` is set as `role`, in my environment, the `copyRequiresWriterPermission` is `true` and the copy and download cannot be done even when the notification mail is sent. How about this?

Comment: By the way, when above situation is different from my environment, for example, how about sending an email with `MailApp` and `GmailApp` instead of `Drive.Permissions.insert`? In this case, I thought that your goal can be achieved. But I'm not sure whether this suggestion is the same direction with you. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks again. I tried changing the order of the operations my function does (first `Drive.permissions.insert` then update the labels) but there's no difference. I'll definitely look into your solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198377/gdrive-disable-copying-and-downloading). I also thought of alternate ways of sending the notification, maybe inclunding a link to the file. But the "built-in" feature in `Drive.permissions.insert` seemed quite convenient.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad you could obtain the direction you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question because (as suggested also by Tanaike) sending the notification via `MailApp` instead of `Drive.Permissions.insert` does the trick. Even when the email includes the URL of the shared file, the file itself stays restricted.

At variance with this behaviour, `emailMessage` in `Drive.Permissions.insert` apparently attaches a copy of the restricted file to the email notification, thus defeating the purpose of the restriction.

I'm pasting the new version of my function below (notice I had to change the first argument a little bit, in order to get the URL inside the function). I'm not sure whether this is the best way of doing that, I'm still a bit confused about file id's and file handles in DriveApp.

Also, I'm still curious about the behaviour of `emailMessage` in `Drive.Permissions.insert`.

```
function shareFile(hfile,addr,role,opt,msg){
  var sendNotifications;
  var Id = hfile.getId();  
  var fileId = Drive.Files.get(Id);
  
  var URL = hfile.getUrl();

  
  // changes the labels in order to restrict access
  if(opt == 0) fileId.labels.restricted = true;
  else fileId.labels.restricted = false;
  
  // update labels
  Drive.Files.update(fileId, Id);
  //Logger.log('File "%s", restricted label is (2): %s', fileId.title, fileId.labels.restricted);
   
  // notifications
  if(msg==="") sendNotifications='false';
  else sendNotifications='true';
  
  
  Drive.Permissions.insert(
        {
         'role': role,
         'type': 'user',
         'value': addr
        },
        Id,
        {
         'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
         });
  
  if(msg!==""){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: addr,
      subject: "file condiviso",
      htmlBody: 'troverai il file nella sezione "Condivisi con me" del tuo Google Drive.' + 'oppure seguendo questo <a href="' + URL +'">questo link</a>'
  });
  
  } 
  
 
 
  

         
}
```

Here `opt=0` and `role='reader'`.